# To run nodejs file on my domain

Tags: node.js, localhost

Presently I have created one simple file in Nodejs which run well on my localhost:8080. But I want to run this file on my personal domain. So what help setting need to do to run on my personal domain ex: xyz.com

This is my simple code for nodejs which is running fine on localhost

```
<pre>  

 var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  if (request.url === '/') {
    response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
    response.end('<strong>obligatory bear!</strong>');
  }
});

server.listen(8080, function () {
  console.log('Im listening on port 8080');
});
</pre>
```

Comment: 1. Install node.js on your hosting server using the credentials.
2. Run it on the hosting server by accessing the terminal. The same way you are running it on your local system.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Luke

Answer (score 0):

add line

```
127.0.0.1    xyz.com
```

in you /etc/hosts!!!
And then you can access you site on **xyz.com:8080**.
to edit hosts file open the file in super user mode.

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/hosts
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, But I want other user also able to access this file like example we upload index.html on xyz.com and other user can access through url xyz.com/index.html. <br> how can other user can can access any idea?