# To run nodejs file on a real domain

Tags: node.js, npm, dns, servermanager

Citations: [To run nodejs file on my domain](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36280385/19912183)

Is there a way to do like this?

```
npm run app.js --someAction? realdomain.com:80
```

- my case is just to run a simple single file.
- don't want use any web server Apache or nginx.
- don't want any env file.
- don't want change /etc/hosts.
- and there is no way to change client side /etc/hosts.

Comment: You can try using [mdns](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multicast-dns). Why do you need this?